# Django: email sender is the same as the recipient sender , How i can resolve that

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-settings

I have developed a form contact where the user can contact us he will type his email, the subject and the message, But am stuck on after some tries I didn't succeed to reach my goal , everything is good the email is send to the email recipient that i have mentioned in `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

But the email sender is registered as the email recipient i do no why ,Here is the code:

```
def contact_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return render(request, 'pages/success.html')
    return render(request, 'pages/contact.html', {'form': form})
```

How i can resolve that i don't want the sender email be the recipient email , i want it to be the email that user will entered during fill out the form.

Answer (score 0):

Funtion `send_email` accepts arguments: `subject`, `message`, `from_email`, `[to]`. You are basically sending mail from and to your `EMAIL_HOST_USER`, because practically `from_email` does not matter this much (it might change name, but definitely not e-mail address itself). Backend is taken from `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and it's password, port etc.

Think about that on this way:

Should it be really that easy to send e-mail as any address?

Comment: So isn't possible to make the sender email : Be the email that the user enter it in the contact form!

Comment: Let's say the user enters mail from your bank that you trust and gives you link with fake login page. You think that would be safe for people to easily manipulate e-mails they send mails from? :)

Comment: Okay , I understood thanks.